# How to fetch all same value field like categories and its subcategories?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, categories

I am actually facing problem with a sql query execution which I am failing to execute as I want.

For a brief of what I want :
Here's my table structure-

```
| id | categoryname | nameofthing | 
| 1  |   category1  |    name 1   |
| 2  |   category2  |    name 2   |
| 3  |   category 3 |    name 3   |
| 4  |   category 1 |    name 4   |
| 5  |   category 1 |    name 5   |
| 6  |   category 3 |    name 6   |
```

And what I want to display the results is like:

```
Category1 
 - Name 1
 - Name 4
 - Name 5
Category2
 - Name 2
Catergot3
 - Name 3
```

and so on..

I want to run a query which first fetch all the samevalue categoryname and then its values( nafeofthing ) and again next samevalye categoryname and their value.

Please help me achieve this!

```php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thing WHERE tol_id='$bid' ORDER BY categoryname, name"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $categoryname = $row['categoryname'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo"
    <div class='stuff'>
    <p>".$categoryname."</p>
        <div id='rowstuff'>
            <div id='name'>".$tname."</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thing WHERE tol_id='$bid' ORDER BY categoryname, name"); 
$categories = [];
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $categories[$row['categoryname']][] = $row['name'];
    }
}
if(!empty($categories)) {
    foreach($categories as $categoryName => $subCategories) {
        echo "<div class='stuff'>
                <p>".$categoryName."</p>
                <div id='rowstuff'>";
                if(!empty($subCategories)) {
                    foreach($subCategories as $subCategory) {
                        echo "<div id='name'>".$subCategory."</div>";
                    }
                }
        echo "</div></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I also want to echo some other data associated with subcategories like if its an product then its price and so on, how to retrieve that too with this foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is best done at the application layer, but you can get this result from a query:

```
select coalesce(concat('- ', nameofthing), categoryname)
from ((select categoryname, null as nameofthing
       from thing t
      ) union all
      (select categoryname, nameofthing
       from thing t
      )
     ) t
order by categoryname, (nameofthing = null) desc;
```

Comment: what is t here? is it tablename?

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma . . . `t` is for the table name.  And sadly, your comment ("sadly it is not working") is of no use at all.  If there is an error, you should specify it.  If it produces incorrect results, you should explain.

Comment: Then here it goes: The code returns and error where it states - mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .....

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma . . . There is no obvious syntax error in the answer.  I suspect it is something in your code.

Comment: I checked your code in phpmyadmin through SQL execution, it did worked but the results were not as expected, it was showing categories twice one with its nameofthing and other without it..

Comment: I guess it must be error of php version I am using or the code I wrote, btw thank you so much for your affirm answers. It might not have helped but it indeed made me learn of a way to execute SQL I was unaware of. :) FYI above Vinay's code worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
       <?php
        //use GROUP_CONCAT to CONCAT all name by comma(,) group by categoryname. 'thing' is your table name
        $query = "SELECT categoryname, GROUP_CONCAT(nameofthing) as 'name' FROM thing group by categoryname ORDER BY categoryname";

        $output ='';
    $query= mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $categoryname = $row['categoryname'];
        $output.="<p>".$categoryname."</p>";

        //using explode split the name in array
        $name = explode(',', $row['name']);

        $output.="<div id='rowstuff'>";

        //iterate the name from array
        for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++){
             $output.= "<div id='name'>".$name[$i]."</div>";
        }
         $output.= "</div>";
    }
}

    echo $output;
```

OutPut will be like

https://www.screencast.com/t/ZWG7bqy0

Comment: Now check. I forgot to add , within explode function

Comment: Returns this error:  Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .....

Comment: Just debug your code. It's working - https://www.screencast.com/t/ZWG7bqy0

Comment: use the query with connection param like - $query= mysqli_query($conn, $query); I'm using mysqli_query you can check with mysql_query